# How to partition table on Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, guid-partition-table

A table named demo,now need to partition it just like demo1,demo2,demo3,....,demo10

So how to partition the table on Yii2?

I probably known should add a method getTableName in Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the related model

the tableName function return the table name

```
class YouModel  extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'yourTableName' . $YourNumber ;
    }
    ......
```

Comment: are you saying the the above coede will create a partition ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam No. He's giving idea on how to handle the partitioned table in model

Comment: @pown that is not the question that is asked. OP says  "So how to partition the table on Yii2?" maybe the question needs more clarification. also the above will throw error because there is nothing defined for `$YourNumber` neither any value is passed as params

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam  you are not asking  ..  are commenting ..  if you have a real question post a new question with proper detail .. and eventually  comment me the link  ..  anyway this answer if not for partitioning table but for manage a multi tenancy table

Comment: its not something to get into conflict/debate I think, what is clearly written i posted in my comment too. and YES your code will throw error